# How to convert a character timestamp into a date-time object in R

Tags: r, datetime

There is a timestamp variable (i.e. UTC) in my data frame which is a character / string and the date-time format is as follows:-

> Fri Aug 10 04:42:47 +0000 2012

How to convert it into a date-time object in R? I tried using the following but it is giving me NAs.

> data1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(data1$UTC),origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT")

Comment: You need to specify the `format` of you date

Comment: Read `?as.POSIXct` and `?strptime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for your example.  See `?strptime` for the format codes.

```
as.POSIXct("Fri Aug 10 04:42:47 +0000 2012",format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y",tz="GMT")

[1] "2012-08-10 04:42:47 GMT"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`, which saves you the typing of spaces and `%` signs:

```
date_string = "Fri Aug 10 04:42:47 +0000 2012"

library(lubridate)

parse_date_time(date_string, "abdHMSzY", tz = "GMT")
# [1] "2012-08-10 04:42:47 GMT"
```